# Should I make a different join table for the same type of relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, polymorphic-associations

I have posts that can be voted on by a polymorphic association. Now I am making comments votable as well. Can I share the same models and logic for this for my comments? Or do I have to make a new model relationship ?

```
#post.rb
has_many                      :votes, :as => :votable                          
has_many                      :voting_users,                                   
                              :through => :votes,                              
                              :source => :user 
#vote.rb
belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to copy the two has_many relationships from your post model and drop them in comment.rb without a problem.  Since your vote model is polymorphic, as long as you have `votable_id:integer` and `votable_type:string` in the `votes` table, everything should work normally.